# Mock current_account on Padrino for rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec, padrino

I'm trying to test a padrino controller that depends on current_account provided by Padrino::Admin::AccessControl

To do so, I need to mock current_account.

the code is something like:

```
App.controller :post do
  post :create, map => '/create' do
    Post.create :user => current_account
  end
end
```

and the rspec:

```
describe "Post creation" do
  it 'should create' do
    account = Account.create :name => 'someone'
    loggin_as account #to mock current_account
    post '/create'
    Post.first.user.should == account
  end
end
```

How can I implement "loggin_as" or how can I write this test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple way to test:

```
App.any_instance.stub(:current_account).and_return(account)
```

So, the test code should be:

```
describe "Post creation" do
  it 'should create' do
    account = Account.create :name => 'someone'
    App.any_instance.stub(:current_account).and_return(account)
    post '/create'
    Post.first.user.should == account
  end
end
```

but I still like to build "loggin_as" helper. So, how can I dynamically get App class? (should I create another thread for this question?)

Comment: gotcha. To get app class just use "app" instead of "App"

Comment: Sure cpeireira ? Because I get :

     Failure/Error: app.any_instance.stub(:current_account).and_return(@admin)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `any_instance' for #<Padrino::Router:0x007fc905c20a08>

Comment: what rspec and padrino versions are you using?

Comment: padrino 0.12.0 and rspec 2.14. 
I finally ended up doing it this way : https://gist.github.com/leucos/10231670
 - Thanks !